# Specialization of the variable by configuration type in premake

Tags: premake

I'm using premake5 with Visual Studio 2013 and try to link a third-party library to my project. Debug version of this library has the "d" suffix as usual. This is the sample script.

```
solution "MySln"
    language "C++"
    configurations { "debug", "release" }

    d = ""

    configuration "debug"
        d = "d"

    configuration "release"
        d = ""

    libicu = { "icuin%{d}", "icuuc%{d}" }

project "core"
    kind "SharedLib"
    location "core"
    links(libicu)
    files { "core/**.h", "core/**.cpp" }
```

But this script links in both configurations (debug and release) icuin.lib and icuuc.lib. If I remove **d = ""** assignment in **configuration "release"** block then the both configurations link icuind.lib and icuucd.lib libraries. It looks as if premake uses the latest seen definition of the variable in resolving of %{d} placeholder. How can I change my script to obtain the correct behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix variable assignments (which are evaluated at script evaluation time) and Premake configurations (which are assembled after all project scripts are run) like that.

One solution could be:

```
solution "MySln"
   language "C++"
   configurations { "debug", "release" }

   filter "configurations:debug"
      targetextension "d"

project "core"
   kind "SharedLib"
   location "core"
   files { "core/**.h", "core/**.cpp" }

   filter "configurations:debug"
      links { "icuind", "icuucd" }
   filter "configurations:release"
      links { "icuin", "icuuc" }
```

If you have lots of libraries or do this often you can use a function for it:

```
project "core"
   links_d { "icuin", "icuuc" }

function links_d(value)
   filter("configurations:debug")
   for i = 1, #value do
       links (value[i] .. "d")
   end
   filter("configurations:release")
   links (value)
   filter("*")
end
```